# ajax get empty array from json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So I have this php class where i have a function that get users from a PSQL database but the AJAX keep loging empty array in the console:

```
public function getUsers(){
        $query = pg_query(self::$DBH, "select id, name, email, admin from users order by name;");
        $result = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($query)) {
            $result[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I use a phphandler file to call the function from ajax
:

```
<?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bdd.php';
    require_once 'modele_backend.php';
    $module = new Modele_Backend();
    echo json_encode($module -> getUsers());



?>
```

and finaly there is the AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#user_email").on("input", function(){
                    // Print entered value in a div box
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'modules/mod_backend/backendHandler.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
                    });
                });
            });
```

The problem is that js keep showing empty array in the console.

The json_encode works fine as json_last_error = 0.

I Tried replacing the return of my getUsers() function by

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

to test if the function manage to encode my array and it did show up like a JSON on the page so this is not a encoding of my array problem. Still when AJAX get the result of the json_encode function it display an empty array.

Thanks for any help !

Necro.

Comment: What's exactly the output of `console.log(response)`? `[]`, `undefined`, some kind of object...?

Comment: Checking `json_last_error` doesn't tell you how many rows are returned from the query

Comment: Yes the console output []

Comment: i know, json_last_error  tells you if json encode went well. But the query do return rows, i tested it out of ajax multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
You have to set content type of header in your php file before echo

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

**Solution 2**
change `dataType` in your ajax code to `html`
or remove it to return default `dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))`

and then convert returned string to json using javascript [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method .

Answer (score 0):

It turned ou the problem was not json_encode at all, it was a problem with my static DB class wich I was includong twice with the AJAX call.

Thanks anyway for the support